# Android OpenGL ES transformations with finger gestures for 2D

Tags: android, opengl-es, transformation

Is there a sample code for applying 2D transformation: rotate, scale, translate for 2D OpenGL ES scene, using finger gestures. Something similar to [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2591-opengl-es-transformations-with-gestures), but for Android instead for iPhone? I have searched everywhere, but i could not found any useful source code.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to obtain the coordinates of the OpenGL from the pixel coordinates of the fingers. In SurfaceView class defines event handling methods:

```
public class SurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView implements
        GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, 
        GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {
    private GestureDetectorCompat detector;
    private CoordinatesOpenGL coordinatesOpenGL;
    private volatile float xPress; 
    private volatile float yPress;

    public SurfaceView() {
        ...
        detector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, this);
        detector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
        coordinatesOpenGL = new CoordinatesOpenGL();
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return mDetector.onTouchEvent(e) || super.onTouchEvent(e);
    }
    // event handling methods
    @Override public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) { ... return true; }
    @Override public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) { return true; }
    @Override public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) { ... return true; }
    @Override public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) { ... return true; }
    @Override public void onShowPress(MotionEvent event) { ... return true; }
    @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) { ... return true; }
    @Override public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
        float distanceX, float distanceY) { ... return true; }
    @Override public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {}
    @Override public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
        float v1, float v2) { ... return true; }
```

Then, in one of these methods, the coordinates of OpenGL are calculated:

```
@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
    coordinatesOpenGL.fromDisplay(renderer.getWidthDisplay(),
        renderer.getHeightDisplay(),
        event.getX(), event.getY());
    xPress = coordinatesOpenGL.getXGL(); // get OpenGL coordinates x[-1; 1], y[-1; 1]
    yPress = coordinatesOpenGL.getYGL();
    renderer.setPassXY(xPress, yPress); // pass x, y to render 
    return true;
}
```

To calculate the OpenGL coordinates, I wrote a method (on Kotlin), but maybe there are other standard functions:

```
fun fromDisplay(displayWidth: Int, displayHeight: Int,
                    displayX: Float, displayY: Float) {
    val offsetX: Float // offset X-axis (pixels)
    val offsetY: Float // offset Y-axis (pixels)

    val centerX = displayWidth / 2 // x of screen center (pixels)
    val centerY = displayHeight / 2 // y of screen center (pixels)

    if (displayX <= centerX && displayY >= centerY) { // left-down quarter
        offsetX = (centerX - displayX)
        offsetY = (displayY - centerY)
        xGL = -(offsetX / centerX)
        yGL = -(offsetY / centerY)
    } else if (displayX <= centerX && displayY <= centerY) { // left-up quarter
        offsetX = (centerX - displayX)
        offsetY = (centerY - displayY)
        xGL = -(offsetX / centerX)
        yGL = offsetY / centerY
    } else if (displayX >= centerX && displayY <= centerY) { // rigth-up quarter
        offsetX = (displayX - centerX)
        offsetY = (centerY - displayY)
        xGL = offsetX / centerX
        yGL = offsetY / centerY
    } else if (displayX > centerX && displayY > centerY) { // rigth-down quarter
        offsetX = (displayX - centerX)
        offsetY = (displayY - centerY)
        xGL = offsetX / centerX
        yGL = -(offsetY / centerY)
    }
}
```

In Render class use OpenGL coordinates to move objects:

```
...
Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, x, y, z)
...
public void setPassXY(Float passX, Float passY) {
    ...
    x = xPass * aspect; // or yPass * aspect - depending on orientation
    y = yPass;
    ...
}
```

With rotation and scale by analogy.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it, but do you know if there is a full working example with source code for all transformations Scale, Translate and Rotate. Somewhere in github, where I can see the full source code.

Comment: @slaviboy You can see here (author andresoviedo): https://github.com/andresoviedo/android-3D-model-viewer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/andresoviedo/app/model3D/controller/TouchController.java